# how add foreign key to another table laravel with the function construct in the cart model.Im very new to laravell i just wanted to know whats goin on

Tags: laravel

I have 2 table one is cart and one is deliveries. Every time  there is someone trying to add product into the cart  data will be added to cart and delivery as well. but i dnt know how to implement that .
[image]

if I run this code like this
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide the code as text in a code block not as images, thank you :)

Comment: public function add_to_cart(Request $request){
   
          $cart =  new Cart();
          $cart->Brandname = $request->Brandname;
          $cart->product_id = $request->product_id;
          $cart->status = 0;
          $cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
          $cart->price = $request->price;
          $cart->user_id = $request->user_id;
          $cart->save();
   
          $delivery =  new delivery();
          $delivery->fk_cart_id = $cart->id;
          $delivery->status = 0;
          $delivery->save();
   that is my code in saving data into two table.

Comment: @hjean Instead of screenshots paste in your code

Comment: i alrady add my code here